# Picture issue with Skype on Logitech HD Webcam C525 since Windows 10 1903

Tags: windows-10, skype, webcam, logitech-webcam, windows-10-v1903

Recently my system was updated to Windows 10 1903. My webcam has been working fine up to this point, but now in Skype, the camera image is distorted. In a video call, the image looks normal to whoever I'm connected with, and also in Windows' Camera app, but in Skype, it's messed up. (See screenshot)
[Webcam distorted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Lmc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall Skype and reinstall the latest build from official website

Open the Skype app and select Tools > Options to open further settings, check the webcam configurations

Besides, refer to this article below for more troubleshoot methods

https://windowsreport.com/skype-camera-not-working-windows-10/

Comment: Uninstall/reinstall was the first thing I tried: Skype is a Windows Store app now, BTW. Drivers are current, and as I stated in the question, I don't see this issue in other programs.